# process running slow via crontab

Tags: python, multithreading, cron

I'm trying to run a python process which has two threads. When I run it via crontab one of the thread shows D in status S of htop resulting in very very slow completion of tasks

The python process has to do socket writes. When I run it from command line it works fine. Can someone tell what the issue can be.